Does EF Core have the ability to add an extension to an existing docker Postgres database
As title says: I have a .NET 8 application, using Entity Framework Core, with the application and database running on Docker containers. I would like to add postgres-uuidv7-sql to the current existing database.
I have googled round and not seeing anything re this particular situation that suits... Can anyone point to something solid on this scenario?
EDIT: More information (below)
I am using code-first method, hence looking for a way to add the Postgres extension via using Migrations

User-defined function mapping

and "cousin" to Peko's answer.  see these 2 : https://anuraj.dev/blog/how-to-execute-storedprocedure-in-ef-core/%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations     but please post your final answer (if someone does not post an exact accepted answer)....when you figure it out.  I'm curious with the postgres "extras".
